# Переменные в css, как считать calc

Tags: html, css, css3

Я хочу, используя переменную `var(--a)` посчитать значение `var(--b)`
Я хочу из `4 rem`, которые в переменной `var(--a)` получить `-4.7rem` в переменной `var(--b)`, но css что-то не считает

```css
:root {
  --a: 4rem;
  --b: calc(-(var(--a)+0.7rem));
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  font-size: var(--a);
}

b {
  font-size: var(--b);
}
```

```html
<a>123</a>
<b>aбв</b>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--b: calc(-1 * (var(--a) + 0.7rem));`

Только учтите что отрицательного font-size не бывает. Он будет нулевым.

Comment: Да, мне не для `font-size` нужно, а для позиционирования элементов, с помощью `margin-top`, `top`, `left`

Answer (score 1):

Первое: у вас в calc минус вначале воспринимается как оператор вычитания, но нет исходного числа. Браузер не воспримет правильно конструкцию calc(-***). Используйте умножение на `-1` или вычитание из 0.

Второе: операторы должны быть отделены пробелами.

неправильно:

```
calc(-(var(--a)+0.7rem));
```

правильно:

```
calc(0 - (var(--a) + 0.7rem));
```